# creating new dataframe from existing dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a hard time understanding how to create a new dataframe based on elements from an existing dataframe. [Here's an example of my current dataframe, and the new dataframe I'd like to populate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrL4f.png)

The dataframes do not have the same column structure.

The problem I'm having is twofold:

1. The current df has repeats, which I do not want in my new dataframe. I can't simply remove duplicates from the current df, because they exist for a reason. For example, as can be seen in the image, I have several rows with the same Incident Number. I would like to have a row in the new df with the Incident Number appearing only once.

I envisioned something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
for x in current_df['Incident Number']: 
    if x in new_df['Incident Number']: 
        pass
    else:
        new_df['Incident Number'].append(x)
```

2. Once I have all the non-duplicated Incident Numbers in the new df, I don't know how to populate the columns of the new df based on aspects of the current df.

For example, for each Incident Number in current_df, if current_df['Treatment Name.1'] == 'Manual Defibrillation' then new_df['Defibrillation']==True for that same Incident Number..

Would anyone know how to do this?

Thank you for the help, I hope this is clear!

Comment: For your first question, you sort with the incident number, `data.sort_values(" incident number", inplace=True)`  and then  drop duplicate values 
`data.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The first part can be accomplished by creating a data-frame from the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) incident numbers, like so:

```
new_df = pd.Dataframe(current_df['Incident Number'].unique(), columns=['Incident Number'])
```

The next part is essentially how you wrote it out. The important thing here is to note the use of [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to drop redundant occurrences of the incident numbers.

```
new_df['Defibrillation'] = current_df.drop_duplicates(subset='Incident Number', ignore_index=True)['Treatment Name.1'] == 'Manual Defibrillation'
```

`new_df` now has two columns, one for the unique incident numbers and another for the truth value corresponding to the value of the treatment names. More columns can be created in a similar manner.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. By dropping the duplicates in the second solution, I am missing events where for a particular Incident Number, there was Manual Defibrillation, because the column Treatment Name.1 can have CPR, Oxygen, Manual Defibrillation in separate rows for the same Incident Number. This is why the duplicates are important. Any help to overcome this?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a new column using a combination of columns `Incident Number` and some object mapping categories of `Treatment Name.1` to numbers assuming that this pair will be unique. You could use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to do that quickly -- I'll try to update my answer shortly.